# MySQL order by not working with division

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

Guyz. I have a problem that I can't solve with mysql query.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4ogG.png) is what I've got.

I need something like `ORDER BY Rating = Rating / nrrates`, but it's not working properly.

Comment: Please post your query as plain text, not an image link. Anyway, unless `nrrates` is equal to 1, `Rating = Raint/nrrates` will always be false. It's not clear what you're trying to do with that.

Comment: Did you try with `ORDER BY Rating / nrrates`?

Comment: Welcome to the wiki. See How To [Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) and/or [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
ORDER BY Rating / nrrates
```

to order by the average rating.